# Retrieving data from a file and generation dynamic table

Tags: php, file, dynamic, html-table, fopen

I have a file File3:

```
[File3] 
Time | Name | Name | ID1 | ID2 
15:50 | Alex | Web | * 38 | 5 
10:50 | Xyz | Xxx | * 55 | 65 
10:50 | Volume | Xxx | 55 | 65 
12:50 | Kate | Uh | 35 | 62 
15:50 | Maria | Zzz | 38 | 67
```

The file is generated and the time can only have one line and the next time may be 30

I'm not good at writing in PHP, wants to write a script that will download a file and loaded into a dynamic table PHP 
lines with logos marked with [*] base the entire row should be red.

Result:

```
====================================
| Time | Name |Surname| ID1  | ID2 |
====================================
|15:50 | Alex |  Web  | * 38 |  5  | - red color background
====================================
|10:50 | Xyz  |   Xxx | * 55 | 65  | - red color background
====================================
|10:50 | asd  |   Xxx | 55   | 69  |
====================================
|12:50 | Kate |   Uh  | 35   | 62  |
====================================
|15:50 | Maria|   Zzz | 38   | 67  |
====================================
```

My script php in html:

```
<div class="Xyz" style="width:800px;height:50px;">
<?php
print "<h1 align=\"left\"> </br></h1>";
$file = fopen("File3.txt", "r");
while (false !== ($line = fgets($file))) {
$wynik=explode("+",$line);
$wynik=array_slice($wynik,0,10);
$grid=pc_grid_horizontal($wynik,10);
print $grid;
}
function pc_grid_horizontal($array, $size) {
    $table_width = 100;
    $width = intval($table_width / $size);
    $tr = '<tr align="center">';
    $td = "<td width=\"$width%%\">%s</td>";
    $grid = "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 width=\"$table_width%\">$tr";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $e) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, $e);
        $i++;
        if (!($i % $size)) {
            $grid .= "</tr>$tr";
        }
    }

    while ($i % $size) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, '&nbsp;');
        $i++;
    }
    $end_tr_len = strlen($tr) * -1;
    if (substr($grid, $end_tr_len) != $tr) {
        $grid .= '</tr>';
    } else {
        $grid = substr($grid, 0, $end_tr_len);
    }
    $grid .= '</table>';

    return $grid;
}
?>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something much simpler?  You don't actually need to style the entire table using ancient HTML attributes. You can use css from an external stylesheet.

For example:

```
<?php
$file = file('File3.txt');

$table = array();
foreach($file as $line=>$content) {
   $parts = explode('|', $content); // turn your single line into an array of fields
   $parts = array_map('trim',$parts); // trim off any spaces from all parts
   if($line == 0) {
      $class = 'header'; // class for the header, that is the first line of the table
   } elseif($parts[3][0] == '*') {
      $class = 'emphasis'; // class for a row that needs to be red
   } else {
      $class = ''; // no class usually
   }
   $table[] = '<tr class="'.$class.'"><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $parts) . '</td></tr>';
}

echo '<table id="yourTbl">', implode("\r\n", $table), '</table>';
```

then you add CSS containing:

```
table#yourTbl {
   width: xx px; /* set to whatever width you want the table to be. If you wrap it in a <div> with a fixed with, you can change this one to 100% */
}
#yourTbl td {
   /* default style for all table data fields. Overwritten for specific fields in the next 2 definitions */
   text-align: center; /* make sure all values are centered inside the table */
}
/* your first row, with the table heading */
#yourTbl tr.header td {
   font-weight: bold;
}
/* your row with emphasis, which contains a * */
#yourTbl tr.emphasis td {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: I would use `' | '` (including the spaces) inside the `explode()` call.

Comment: I don't know how his data is formatted exactly. Nor do I know if any pipes are escaped, or if they're even allowed inside values. Just in case, I explode on '|' and then trim the whitespace off of it later.

Comment: I made a test and I get an error: Parse error: 
syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in index.php on line 14
14 line in script: foreach($file as $line=>$content) {

Comment: Replace `$table = array()` for `$table = array();` (add semicolon).

Comment: I found in linii 13 lacking ";"

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. Wrote it off the top of my head, easy to make typo's. Corrected it in the answer. Thank you for spotting it :)